# Date Time function producing incorrect result in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have this function in PHP:

```
function dt_utc_to_local($dt_utc, $timezone)

{

$dt_utc2 = new DateTimeImmutable($dt_utc, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dt_local_time = $dt_utc2->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone)); 
$dt_local_time_formated = $dt_local_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$dt_now_utc = new DateTimeImmutable(gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s"), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dt_now_local_time = $dt_now_utc->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
$now_dt_local_time_formated = $dt_now_local_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

return array($now_dt_local_time_formated, $dt_local_time_formated );

}
```

That I call using:

```
$msg_date = '2022-09-14 12:00:00';
$timezone = 'America/New_York';

list($dt_now_local_time, $dt_local_time ) = dt_utc_to_local($msg_date, $timezone);
```

This is to convert UTC datetime that I have in a MySql database to local datetime, but for some reason `$dt_now_local_time` keeps giving me the date of September 13 and today is 14.

If I use the same code without a function, it works well.

Any idea?

Comment: When it, just this second, became the 14th day of September in the UTC timezone, which is around the UK, then it is still the 13th in New York.

Comment: Yes, it was a bad example, i corrected the time, and still the same.

Comment: No, it's not the same, see: https://3v4l.org/RHH3E

Comment: Still what is giving me trouble is the date-time right now, not the mysql stored data.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Storing UTC in the database is a good idea, you can easily convert that to any time zone.

Comment: Well thanks, I did not know that tool, apparently everything works well with that code, then the problem may be somewhere else because I still get the day 13, in my own app I mean.

Comment: OK, I understand. Good bug hunting.

Comment: Yes, I just test the code. It works as expected.